# How to open a Facebook Page using Phonegap and Phonegap Connect

Tags: facebook, cordova, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have an application where I use phonegap connect to login with the native facebook application. Now i want to open a page out of this application. But unfortunately when i open the page in the webbrowser (inapp browser of phonegap) the user is not logged in and has to use his credentials.

`window.open("http://facebook.com/SomePage", '_blank', 'location=yes');`

I would like to have a possibility to open a facebook page out of javascript in the native application.

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I know now how to solve this. You just have to use the Facebook namespace like fb:// then everything works (as long as the facebook app is installed).